# Top layer in JLayeredPane not displaying

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to create a panel that uses a JLayeredPane to have a panel centered above another, larger panel. I can't seem to get the smaller panel to display though. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
private JLayeredPane pane;
private AllPlayersPanel players; //Larger panel, uses circleLayout
private GamePanel game; //Smaller panel, simple BorderLayout

public MainPanel(){
    super();
    setSize(900, 900);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,  BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));       

    pane = new JLayeredPane();
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));     

    players = new AllPlayersPanel();
    players.setPreferredSize(players.getPreferredSize());
    players.setLocation(0,0);
    //players.setOpaque(false);
    pane.add(players, new Integer(0));

    game = new GamePanel();
    game.setPreferredSize(game.getPreferredSize());
    game.setLocation(385, 405);
    //game.setOpaque(false);        
    pane.add(game, new Integer(2));

    add(pane);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JComponent newPane = new MainPanel();
    newPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

I've tried every combination of .setOpaque() I can think of as well.

CircleLayout can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CircleLayout.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're using `setSize` when you shouldn't be and `preferredSize` when you don't need to...

For example.

In you constructor of the `MainPanel` you call `setSize(900, 900);` when you should have overridden `getPreferredSize` then on the panels you are adding to the `JLayeredPane` you're calling `setPreferredSize` but the `JLayeredPane` has no layout manager with which to check this value, so the size of these panels remain as 0x0.

Besides, I'm not sure what you expected to gain from calling `players.setPreferredSize(players.getPreferredSize());`, which basically will set the preferred size to 0x0 any way :P

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLayeredPane pane;
    private JPanel players; //Larger panel, uses circleLayout
    private JPanel game; //Smaller panel, simple BorderLayout

    public MainPanel() {
        super();
//        setSize(900, 900);
//        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        pane = new JLayeredPane();
//        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
        pane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));

        players = new JPanel();
        players.setBackground(Color.RED);
        players.setSize(getPreferredSize());
        players.setLocation(0, 0);
        //players.setOpaque(false);
        pane.add(players, new Integer(0));

        game = new JPanel();
        game.setSize(game.getPreferredSize());
        game.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        game.setLocation(385, 405);
        //game.setOpaque(false);        
        pane.add(game, new Integer(2));

        add(pane);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(900, 900);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JComponent newPane = new MainPanel();
        newPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was definitely the problem. Any tips on when to use setSize() and setPreferredSize()? Since I obviously don't know how to very well.

Comment: You shouldn't use `setPreferredSize`, but instead should override `getPreferredSize`.  `preferredSize` is used to provide hints to layout managers about how your component would prefer to be laid out. `setSize` should only be used if 1- You're not using a layout manager (as is the case with `JLayeredPane`) or 2- You are creating your own layout manager

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I can keep it straight now.